# Recommended approach for Google Maps on different computers

Tags: android, google-maps, google-cloud-platform

- For Google Maps, we need :
  1) `Maps API key`
  2) `SHA-1 fingerprint to be added to Google Cloud Console.`
  3) `We need to restrict API key to prevent invalid usages(usally in production).`

> What if I have to run the same project on different computers?

- Possible use case I know:

1) `Add SHA-1 fingerprint (Both debug and release) of different computers in Google Cloud Console.`

Any other approach is welcomed.

Comment: We are multiple developers production house and used the first option for this kind of situation.

Comment: @ariefbayu I just want to make sure that google cloud platform api is same for different computers that we want to use or there is different api.

Comment: What specific API will you be using?

Comment: I am using Maps API.

Comment: For production, you'll surely just have one sign key. So, shouldn't be a problem....

Comment: @ariefbayu I have added debug as well as release SHA1 fingerprint in Google Cloud Console and that should not be a problem! What you think?

Comment: yes, that should not be a problem. As a matter of fact, that's the usual way we as developers handle SHA1 for our android app.

Answer (score 0):

For an android app I think using the SHA1 fingerprint is the only way per the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key#restrict_key)